# How to can i start transfer my AttendenceActivity data from Listview to another Listview in another Activity with database

Tags: database, listview, android-intent

I'm trying trying to transfer my listview data in AttendenceActivity to another listview with database to store my data for future reference.

I'm sorry for the bad coding. Still new to this. Plus I'm having a tight dateline for my project any help would be greatly appreciated guys.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AttendenceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView simpleList;
String[] QL1501S;
Button submit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendence);
    // get the string array from string.xml file

    QL1501S = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.QL1501S);
    // get the reference of ListView and Button
    simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    // set the adapter to fill the data in the ListView
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), QL1501S);

    simpleList.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    // perform setOnClickListerner event on Button
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String message = "";
                                  // get the value of selected answers from custom adapter
            for (int i = 0; i < CustomAdapter.selectedAnswers.size(); i++) {
                message = message + "\n" + (i + 1) + " " + CustomAdapter.selectedAnswers.get(i);
            }
            // display the message on screen with the help of Toast.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here's the xml file for the AttendenceActivity.............

```
    <RelativeLayout         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Attendence"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="50dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/simpleListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/submit"
    android:divider="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="#0f0"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the coding of CustomAdapter for the AttendenceActivity

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
String[] QL1501S;               
LayoutInflater inflter;
public static ArrayList<String> selectedAnswers;

public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] questionsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.QL1501S = questionsList;

    // initialize arraylist and add static string for all the questions
    selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < questionsList.length; i++) {
    selectedAnswers.add("Not Marked");
    }
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {return QL1501S.length;}



@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
    }

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
    }

@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
    // get the reference of TextView and Button's
    TextView NameOfStud = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NameOfStud);
    RadioButton Present = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Present);
    RadioButton Absent = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.Absent);
    // perform setOnCheckedChangeListener event on yes button
    Present.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // set Yes values in ArrayList if RadioButton is checked
    if (isChecked)
    selectedAnswers.set(i, "Present");
    }
    });
    // perform setOnCheckedChangeListener event on no button
    Absent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // set No values in ArrayList if RadioButton is checked
    if (isChecked)
    selectedAnswers.set(i, "Absent");

    }
    });
    // set the value in TextView
    NameOfStud.setText(QL1501S[i]);
    return view;
    }

    }
```

Lastly the listview for the Listview Attendence

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- TextView for studentname-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NameOfStud"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="#000" />
<!-- RadioGroup for grouping of RadioButton-->
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Present"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Present"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/Absent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Absent"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:checked="false" />
</RadioGroup>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Remarks"
    android:hint="Remarks" />
```